# How to load external font file in WPF on runtime

Tags: wpf

This question has already been asked and I've tried every given solution but yet it's not working for me.
I have a TTF file somewhere on my hard disk and I try to load and use it when a button is clicked without the use of `XAML`. It's totally dynamic so I don't want to get involved with resources.

Here's my code:

```
var path = @"D:\Fonts\Ashley.ttf";
btn.FontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri(path), "Ashley");
```

But it doesn't work. Can you give me a working solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to directly reference the font file path. You need two things: The directory where the font file exists and the font name.

So in your case you can set the font family using the following code:

```
btn.FontFamily = new FontFamily("file:///d:/Fonts/#Ashley");
```

For reference see chapter [Specifying Fonts in Alternate Directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.aspx) in the MSDN document "FontFamily Class".

Comment: Thanks it finally worked. The MOST IMPORTANT point is not using `Uri` and just passing it as string straightly.